# Selenium - Java - Element gets click but does not action

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriver

Very new to automation and have not had issues until now

I have a button that once clicked , a pop up button appears which one could click and it would perform a certain action.

I get to the second button and it seems to click it , however it does not perform the relevant action

My Code

```
//First Button//
WebElement AddUserSelect =  
chromeDriver.findElementBy.id(
    "j_idt67:j_idt68:j_idt69:j_idt229:pendingTable:dataTable:0:j_idt280_menuButton"));

AddUserSelect.click();

try {
    Thread.sleep(1000L);
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} 

// Second Button//
WebElement AddUser = 

chromeDriver.findElement(By.id(
    "j_idt67:j_idt68:j_idt69:j_idt229:pendingTable:dataTable:0:j_idt281"));
AddUser.click();
```

Element on page when I inspect

```
<a 
    id="j_idt67:j_idt68:j_idt69:j_idt229:pendingTable:dataTable:0:j_idt281" 
    class="ui-menuitem-link ui-corner-all" href="#" 
    onclick="PrimeFaces.ab({s:&quot;j_idt67:j_idt68:j_idt69:j_idt229:pendingTable:dataTable:0:j_idt281&quot;,p:&quot;j_idt67&quot;,u:&quot;j_idt67&quot;,f:&quot;j_idt67&quot;});return false;"
>
    <span class="ui-menuitem-icon ui-icon ui-icon-extlink"></span>
    <span class="ui-menuitem-text">
        Add
    </span>
</a>
```

Any Assistance would be appreciated..Thank you

Comment: Does it perform the action when you click manually? If it "seems" to click it in the test, it means that your test is failing and you need to fix the page itself, not the test.

Comment: @KeyurPotdar Please take care while you edit or approve the edits. OP's initial _HTML_ had 2 `<span>` tags but after 2 simultaneous edits only 1 `<span>` tag remains. OP may not receive any effective Answers. Reverting back to OP's initial version of the question.

Comment: @yarwest Please take care while you edit or approve the edits. OP's initial _HTML_ had 2 `<span>` tags after 2 simultaneous edits only 1 `<span>` tag remains. OP may not receive any effective Answers. Reverting back to OP's initial version of the question.

Comment: @DebanjanB, thanks for noticing that and pinging me. I completely overlooked that. My bad.

Comment: @DebanjanB apologies, might have been my oversight

Comment: Yes it works when clicking manually and thank you very much for the response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the *HTML* you have shared you target the second inner span tag and can use the following *Locator Strategy* to click on the intended element :

```
chromeDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@class='ui-menuitem-link ui-corner-all' and starts-with(@id,'j_idt')]//span[@class='ui-menuitem-text']")).click();
```

---

### Update A

As per your comment update as the previous line of code *locates the element, however does not action* as an alternative you can use the *Javascript Click* as follows :

```
WebElement elem = chromeDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@class='ui-menuitem-link ui-corner-all' and starts-with(@id,'j_idt')]//span[@class='ui-menuitem-text']"));
driver.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", elem);
```

---

### Update B

Induce a waiter through *WebDriverWait* as follows :

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//a[@class='ui-menuitem-link ui-corner-all' and starts-with(@id,'j_idt')]//span[@class='ui-menuitem-text']"))).click();
```

Comment: Hi Thank you , however I tried above it still does not work , it locates the element , however does not action , if you look at the HTML , there is a return false , could that not be causing an issue?

Comment: @SoopaStylin Checkout my answer update and let me know the result.

Comment: ..Still no luck

Comment: JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)chromeDriver; 
 WebElement elem = chromeDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@class='ui-menuitem-link ui-corner-all' and starts-with(@id,'j_idt')]//span[@class='ui-menuitem-text']"));
      js.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", elem);

Comment: @SoopaStylin Check my second answer update and let me know the result.

Comment: No .. the test passes

Comment: Hit There managed to resolve the issue , it would seem it wanted two clicks so I did below and it worked .. thank you very much for your assistance

Comment: WebElement elem = chromeDriver.findElement(By.id("j_idt67:j_idt68:j_idt69:j_idt229:pendingTable:dataTable:0:j_idt281"));
      elem.click();
      
      js.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", elem);